# How to reduce multiple JavaScript request from the server

Tags: javascript, html

How to reduce multiple JavaScript request from the server? which is causing the webpage load slow

Comment: Combine them into 1 file and minify them. Also include than just before the closing body tag.

Comment: check this - https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/optimization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minify your javscript code using

http://jscompress.com/

also make multiple javascript files to one or two and minify it and use

Answer (score 0):

**Bundling** and **Minification** are what you are looking for. Please take a look [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

The provided link is for the asp.net mvc framework.

However, you can apply both bundling and minification to other web frameworks, they are both irrelevant as concepts with the web framework you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can minified you javascript files. There are several online tool which will convert your javascript file to minified.

In order to reduce the page load time you can do the following things :

**Combine Files –** Using external style sheets and scripts is important to keep them from bogging down your page load times, but don’t have more than one CSS and one script file.

**Use CSS Sprites –** When you combine most or all of your images into a sprite, you turn multiple images requests into just one. Then you just use the background-image CSS property to display the section of the image you need.

**Image Maps –** Image maps are not as popular as they once were, but when you have contiguous images they can reduce multiple HTTP image requests down to just one.

Also make use of caching.Browser caching stores cached versions of static resources. This speeds up page speed tremendously and reduces server lag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of FileLoader.js, which can be useful to you (it's also usable with other files than scripts) : https://github.com/Seb-C/FileLoader.js/tree/master

It reduces the number of files and the network load (but not the weight of the files) by loading any files you need from a tar archive.